# Flashbot bundle not included troubleshooting

Tags: flashbots, mev, mev-boost, mev-searcher

I'm trying to send Flashbots bundles on Goerli. I for-loop 10 times to send bundles, every time the target block number increases by 1, in case the previous bundle fails (What I did in [Flashbot bundle is not included because "isSendToMiners" is false](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144756/flashbot-bundle-is-not-included-because-issendtominers-is-false)). This time I set the priority gas price to 500Gwei on Goerli to make sure builders will be likely to consider these bundles. I sent bundles in turn to target blocks from 8560814 to 8560816. As you can see, the first bundle was considered and sealed by some builders. According to https://collective.flashbots.net/t/flashbots-bundle-relay-api-upgrades/896, a bundle being sealed indicates a builder built a full block containing that bundle. Since it had been successfully sealed on block 8560814, why did it not be included? Is it the competition between the builders that causes the validators didn't select these blocks? If I further increase gas price, would that increase the probability of being included in the first block? Or because of the network problem, it is too late when builders received the bundle. In this case, reducing the network delay may solve the problem. Looking forward to your answers.

```
bundleHash:  0x1b3642af122d2ddf89e63a82acbac15844dfc5cb06f853407908ca9d46cd7cee
bundle submitted, waiting 0x1b3642af122d2ddf89e63a82acbac15844dfc5cb06f853407908ca9d46cd7cee
>>>>>>  1
bundle submitted, waiting 0x1b3642af122d2ddf89e63a82acbac15844dfc5cb06f853407908ca9d46cd7cee
Wait Response: BlockPassedWithoutInclusion
{
  BlockNumber: 8560814,
  bundleStats: {
    isHighPriority: true,
    isSentToMiners: false,
    isSimulated: true,
    simulatedAt: '2023-02-26T15:39:45.289Z',
    submittedAt: '2023-02-26T15:39:45.283Z',
    consideredByBuildersAt: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    sealedByBuildersAt: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  },
  userStats: {
    all_time_gas_simulated: '',
    all_time_miner_payments: '',
    is_high_priority: false,
    last_1d_gas_simulated: '',
    last_1d_miner_payments: '',
    last_7d_gas_simulated: '',
    last_7d_miner_payments: ''
  }
}
>>>>>>  2
bundle submitted, waiting 0x1b3642af122d2ddf89e63a82acbac15844dfc5cb06f853407908ca9d46cd7cee
Wait Response: BlockPassedWithoutInclusion
{
  BlockNumber: 8560815,
  bundleStats: {
    isHighPriority: true,
    isSentToMiners: false,
    isSimulated: true,
    simulatedAt: '2023-02-26T15:39:55.861Z',
    submittedAt: '2023-02-26T15:39:55.856Z',
    consideredByBuildersAt: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object]
    ],
    sealedByBuildersAt: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object]
    ]
  },
  userStats: {
    all_time_gas_simulated: '',
    all_time_miner_payments: '',
    is_high_priority: false,
    last_1d_gas_simulated: '',
    last_1d_miner_payments: '',
    last_7d_gas_simulated: '',
    last_7d_miner_payments: ''
  }
}
>>>>>>  3
bundle submitted, waiting 0x1b3642af122d2ddf89e63a82acbac15844dfc5cb06f853407908ca9d46cd7cee
Wait Response: BundleIncluded
Bundle included!
```

Comment: > This time I set the priority gas price to 500Gwei on Goerli to make sure builders will be likely to consider these bundles.

I'm trying to solve a similar problem and I was wondering where you found out that 500 gwei is a correct amount to use

Answer (score 0):

Hello excuse me i see you post multiple time so you need answer but that is need a really clear question for me what you trying to do flashloan ?

What is bundle flashbot precisly for you and related to MEV ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to do flashloan. Flashbots is a research and development organization formed to mitigate the negative externalities posed by Maximal Extractable Value (MEV) to stateful blockchains, starting with Ethereum (from https://www.flashbots.net/). It's not related to flashloan. I'm trying to use Flashbots to send my private transactions to Ethereum block builders. With Flashbots, I can send my transactions (usually in a Flashbots bundle) directly to builders to avoid frontrunning or sandwich attacks.

Comment: Ah ok i understand, and you trying to do it in web3 .. Use a private blockchain maybe its better for you and please if you buy some token don't impact price too much on Swap ... to avoid some problem ... see you soon  :), if you understand how MEV work, change gwei don't really change lot of things in your case ...

Answer (score 0):

On Goerli, it's difficult to include the bundle because there are not many miners that accept flashbots bundle transactions. In my case, the first bundle is successfully included in the target block, but the second bundle doesn't get included in the block. I'm also looking for a solution. Here's the preview:

```
Simulated bundle for block 9333535: SimulatedBundle { hash: 0xdbda209e17d4c2add64dcaf1bdcd8229f0df1bb77796356936a1305a57c4dc44, coinbase_diff: 1380775682315001, coinbase_tip: 0, gas_price: 10391225719, gas_used: 132879, gas_fees: 1380775682315001, simulation_block: 9333531, transactions: [SimulatedTransaction { hash: 0x0c2e70c23bc82b47725baefe47690521ba236d0f108310fc17d8106070c9a79b, coinbase_diff: 1380775682315001, coinbase_tip: 0, gas_price: 10391225719, gas_used: 132879, gas_fees: 1380775682315001, from: 0x3f39c5b139f3adbf94eea553a7bc3e755a76adb7, to: Some(0x588d80a3b5c6d4575b0d2163381402286da51e20), value: Some(Bytes(0x)), error: None, revert: None }] }
About to send bundle for block 9333535...
Bundle for block 9333535 sent...
**Bundle with hash 0xdbda209e17d4c2add64dcaf1bdcd8229f0df1bb77796356936a1305a57c4dc44 was included in target block 9333535**
[2023-07-12T13:40:08Z INFO  Ethers::transactions] Balance: 2748893203715237323248073
[2023-07-12T13:40:08Z INFO  Ethers::transactions] Transaction data for swapTokensForWETHV2: Bytes(0xafd6ccd0000000000000000000000000438358e062fbf63d8e6c20a11d01f60f8c03a9aa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000228fee8c214b02672f0e50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064aeb0bc)
[2023-07-12T13:40:10Z INFO  Ethers::transactions] Bundle for block 9333535 sent...
**[2023-07-12T13:40:17Z INFO  Ethers::transactions] Bundle for block 9333535 was not included in target block.**
```